# Remove chrome extension's "See browsing history" permission request

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's my predicament. 
I am writing an extension for Google Chrome. And it works fine. It's a theme for Google+.

Enough with that. In order to display an icon in the address bar, I need to have "tabs" as part of my permissions. I believe this also causes the web store to say that my extension can access the browser's history. Any way to remedy this?

(Source here: https://github.com/bichiliad/G-Theme)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `tabs` permission for displaying a browser action icon, but you need it for your `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()` in a background page.

`tabs` permission shouldn't trigger "Your browsing history" warning, it's a bug in the gallery. According to [specs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/permission_warnings.html) it should say "Your tabs and browsing activity". I would suggest to submit [a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry).

Comment: Any other way to detect whether or not the user is browsing Google+?
Also, Serg, I feel like you've answered a number of my questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Salem As you are already injecting your content script only to google+, you can send a request in the beginning of your content script to background page telling it to display popup icon.

Comment: For what it's worth, I vaguely remembering this being successful.

Answer (score 4):

It's interesting how few things actually *require* the `"tabs"` permission nowadays.

Quoting the documentation itself (emphasis mine):

> The majority of the `chrome.tabs` API can be used without declaring any permission. However, the `"tabs"` permission is required in order to **populate the `url`, `title`, and `favIconUrl` properties** of Tab.

So you can easily manipulate tabs (e.g. create them) without ever needing the permission.

What's more, when `"activeTab"` permission is active (the extension was invoked for the current tab), the restricted fields **will** be populated if you query for them.

---

One common task that seems to require the `"tabs"` permission is to find a tab with a given address. This used to be impossible without the permission, especially before `query()` was a thing - one would just get all the tabs and filter them by hand.

However, even if you don't have the `"tabs"` permission, you can query by URL pattern. **You do require host permissions for this URL pattern.**

So, suppose you want to know if `www.example.com` is open in some tabs:

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://www.example.com/*"}, function(tabs) {
  // Look, ma, no "tabs"!
});
```

Proof of concept: [GitHub](https://github.com/kav2k/chrome_query_poc)

**Important: this last trick does not work in Firefox WebExtensions.** They unconditionally throw an exception if tabs are queried by URL without `"tabs"` permission. Yes, this is a direct contradiction with the documentation even for Chrome, so it may stop working at some point.

---

Now suppose you still want to know the exact URL (with the above method you can only guess) and the title/favicon for some tabs. Do you still need the `"tabs"` permission?

Depends. If you only need it for a few websites, declare host permissions for them and inject a content script (after querying as above) that harvests this information.

This will lead to a different warning:

> Read and modify your data on {list of websites}

vs the one for `"tabs"`:

> Read your browsing history

In case you are making an extension that makes sense only in the context of those sites, it's a reasonable compromise. If, instead, you're making a generic extension that needs to get this information for websites you don't know in advance - then yes, `"tabs"` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Without the `tabs` permission querying tabs with a URL pattern doesn't work. _Match tabs against one or more URL patterns. Note that fragment identifiers are not matched. Note that **this property is ignored if the extension doesn't have the "tabs" permission**._ Using the `activeTab` permission it _could_ work, but only when the query was initiated by a `pageAction` for example, so you can't execute it from a background script.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert I know it's working because I have deployed extension that work that way (and without `activeTab`). I think there is an additional requirement to have host permissions that cover the pattern you're querying for. Firefox does follow the documentation though - so it's non-portable code.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert [Permissions](https://github.com/kav2k/chandlery/blob/master/src/manifest.json#L37-L41), and [code using `query` this way](https://github.com/kav2k/chandlery/blob/master/src/js/notification.js#L100-L107). FWIW, the code is executed as a "user action", from a notification click - so it does fulfill `activeTab` activation criteria. But I don't have that permission.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert I have created a [minimal PoC](https://github.com/kav2k/chrome_query_poc). Host permissions are required (either explicit or from content scripts), otherwise it would be a security bug.

Comment: You're actually right I must have overlooked something or gave the wrong host permission in my `manifest.json`. Thanks for the PoC :) It works also when listening for the `tabs.onActivated` event also, I'm using it to inject "context menus" into page  selectively.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: This is actually NOT a good practice (more info on the comments bellow). I won't delete this answer just to let others know what not to do.**

---

I had the same issue and solved it by just adding `"http://*/*"` and `"https://*/*"` to the permissions.

Like this:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
```

I don't know exactly why and it doesn't make much sense (does it?), but now the "Read and modify your browsing history" permission message is gone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, and now you get "Read and modify all your data on all websites you visit." instead of "Read and modify your browsing history". This is not an improvement, is it?

Comment: @RobW Oops, I didn't realized that. You're right, this is probably not the way to go. But for what I understood this is a bug right?

Comment: The permission warning is not a bug. The [`tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) documentation is quite clear about the purpose of the `tabs` API: You'll only need the permission if you want to read the `url` or `faviconUrl` properties of the tab objects. With access to these properties, you can construct the history of the user, so in that sense the permission warning is correct.

Comment: @RobW That indeed makes all the sense. I was stuck struggling with the fact that I just wanted to reload my extension options page using the background script (using tab.url). The "read and modify your browsing history" sounded too aggressive given my good intentions. But I guess I will look for another way to do it. Thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: If you want to reload an extension page, use `chrome.extension.getViews({type:'tab'})` to get a list of the `window` (DOMWindow) object of your extension tabs, and invoke the `.location.reload()` method on it (if you wish, use `.location.href` to check whether its URL matches).

Comment: @RobW I solved my problem by saving the options tab ID to reload it after, but that is a much more cleaner solution. Thanks once again, that was very helpful!